# How do you make a menu on the left that stays while the right side scrolls

Tags: javascript, html, css

Like [this](http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) one. I thought it was a frame but apparently is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you a 200PX tall fixed header and footer, a 200PX wide left navigation, and scrollable content area.  here is a [demo](http://jsbin.com/afesa3/2/edit) http://jsbin.com/afesa3/2/edit

```
<div id="header" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; height:200px;right:0px;overflow:hidden;background-color:#FF0000">
    Header
</div>
  <div id="leftNav" style="position:absolute; top:200px; bottom:200px; left:0px; width:200px; overflow:hidden; background-color:#00FF00" >Left Nav</div>
  <div id="rightContent" style="position:absolute; top:200px; bottom:200px; left:200px; right:0px; overflow:auto;background-color:#0000FF">Right Content</div>
  <div id="footer" style="position:absolute; bottom:0px; height:200px; left:0px; right:0px; overflow:hidden;background-color:#FF0000"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

in css: `position: fixed`

Comment: Also, if you ever want to know how someone did an UI element on the web, just look at the source. In Chrome, right click -> inspect element. Firefox -> download firebug. IE -> get development tools.

Comment: In Opera it's right click -> Inspect Element too. And Opera Dragonfly (Opera's built-in dev tool) is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

You need CSS. Try something like:

```
#menu {
    left: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Adjust the values as necessary.